# How to get a skin width and height from it's hostcomponent?

Tags: flex4

[Flex 4] How to get a skin width and height from it's hostcomponent?

Comment: Can you provide some more context?  Are trying to access width and height from within the skin code via the hostComponent, or trying to get the width and height of the skin from within the component?

Comment: I have:
LoginSkin.mxml <- Skin file
LoginView.as <- Class that extends skinnableComponent
Form LoginView I want to know the width of LoginSkin
LoginView contains the setStyle("skinClass", LoginSkin); to link the view to skin

Comment: I'm almost certain that this.width/this.height in your LoginView will reflect the size based on the skin.  Hope that helps.

Comment: but in my views the width and height are 0 :s how can i correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the `width` and `height` from the host component will lead you nowhere as this is a calculated metric generally. And partially it's calculated based on your skin, so you will not know the `height`/`width` at the time your skin is initialized. Try to bind against `hostComponent.width` and you will see in some cases that you will end up in an endless loop.

You should rather work with the `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` properties. For example if you set `bottom` to 0 this means that you want to have it from 0 pixels above the bottom of your component.

For example let's draw a line below your component from left to right:

```
  <s:Line left="0" right="0" bottom="0">
    <s:stroke>
      <s:SolidColorStroke weight="1"/>
    </s:stroke>
  </s:Line>
```